# Clipboard in Google Chrome Frame

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, clipboard, frame

I am deweloping page for IE with Google Chrome Frame. The are any way to copy text to clipboard(without Flash or SL) using this javascript engine or force IE to use orginal engine for some code block?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope, you can't "partially revert" to IE for this (unless you render the whole page with IE, e.g. removing the `<meta>` tag)...and there's no cross-browser non-Flash/SL way to go about it.

If you still need to do this, I'd personally say Flash is your best option, and go with the well proven zeroclipboard: http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/